# Relationship between steering angle and turning angle from centre of mass of a car

Tags: euclidean-geometry, physics, mathematical-modeling

[image: Steering angle of a car diagram]

I'm aware of the [Ackermann Steering Angle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/492593/ackermann-steering-angle), however, I still struggle to come up with an equation that model the relationship between $\dot{x}, \dot{y}$ (the horizontal and vertical velocity of the centre of mass, indicated by yellow dot in the diagram) with the car's velocity($v$) and the steering angle of the wheels (indicated by $\theta L,\:\theta R$ in the diagram)

I want to be able to come up with an expression, assuming that $\theta L=\theta R$. **In other words, how do I come up with an equation that describe the relationship between $\theta$ and $\beta$?**

I suppose that the Ackerman model is based on the fact that $\theta L\neq \theta R$, thus being able to draw a point of rotation outside the car. However, **in the real world, when turning, do actual car have different $\theta$ for its left and right tire?**

What my beliefs are:

1. The car's tire would be constantly slipping in the Ackermann model.
2. The Axle Width (AW), is irrelevant, meaning that the relationship of $\theta$ and $\beta$ is independent of AW, in the equal left and right $\theta$ case.

I come across a website that suggest the relationship to be this for the equal $\theta$ case:
$$
tan(\beta) = \frac{FL}{FL+RL}tan(\theta)
$$
I have no idea how to derive that relationship. **I would really appreciate if someone can please tell me how to come up with that equation or proof that it is correct?** I tried using similar triangles to think in "reverse" for coming with that equation, but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: Why do you think that Ackermann steering would make the tires slip? Where is this website where you found your formula, and what makes you think it is correct?

Comment: This question is double-posted: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/757598

Comment: In the real world, cars do have different steering angles for the left and right tires. https://www.mlep.org/documents/CenterPointSteering.pdf https://suspensionsecrets.co.uk/ackermann/ In racing, where the tires normally do slip a lot in turns, the geometry is quite different. If you don't want slip you have to restrict yourself to only low-speed turns.

Comment: Thanks for your insights! I double post, because I thought that the problem doesn't really fit in the physics SE, because it's becoming to be a pure geometrical thing. I have been trying to find the website on where I found that, but I seem to have lost it. I think it would slip because the rear left and right tire would have to turn at different angular speed. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Oh, it does seem that the rear left and rear right wheel have different angular speed

Comment: It looks like you got an answer on the physics site after all. If the question had been deemed unsuitable for that site it could have been migrated here. (I believe it still could be migrated.)